# Nested flexbox columns with bootstrap 4 displayed wrong on firefox but ok on chrome

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put a column flexbox inside another column flexbox using bootstrap 4.

My goal is to create a mobile menu that has 100vh when the user clicks a button.

The menu area will have three sections which will be populated with different data, while maintaining the top header with the toggle button.

My problem is that in Firefox the second flexbox seems to be stacked horizontally with every element having height: 100%.

In chrome my code seems to work fine.

How can I make my layout consistent?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7o0dej4/5/)

What I'm trying to achieve (Chrome):
[image: chrome screenshot]

What's happening on Firefox:
[image: firefox screenshot]
[image: firefox scrolled right]

Here is my code

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <header class="row sticky-top">
        <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center header-top">
            <div class="col">Left text </div>
            <nav id="navigation" class="main-navigation col">
              <div class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <button>Toggle menu</button>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <div id="mobile-menu-wrapper" class="row flex-column">
            <div class="col-12">Header text</div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <ul id="mobile-menu" class="menu">
                <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              Footer text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
 header {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
}

header .header-top {
  background-color: blue;
}

header.toggled {
  height: 100vh;
}

header.toggled #mobile-menu-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#mobile-menu-wrapper {
  color: black;
  display: none;  
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And the javascript to toggle the menu:

```
var body, header, container, button, menu;
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];

container = document.getElementById('navigation');
button = container.getElementsByClassName('menu-toggle')[0];
button.onclick = function() {
  if (-1 !== header.className.indexOf('toggled')) {
    header.className = header.className.replace(' toggled', '');
  } else {
    header.className += ' toggled';
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are apparently differences for `flexbox` between Chrome and Firefox, and there are bugs as well: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs.

Frankly I don't know what caused your problem but the fix is to just remove `flex-column` on your `#mobile-menu-wrapper` since bootstrap `row` is already `display:flex;` and those `col-12` should make sure it will take up the whole width.

```
<div id="mobile-menu-wrapper" class="row">
    <div class="col-12">Header text</div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul id="mobile-menu" class="menu">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">Footer text</div>
</div>
```

I would suggest either use Bootstrap grid system (which is using `flexbox`) or use your own HTML structure and you style them as `flexbox`. But if you're mixing them, sometimes it will give you surprise.

```
<div id="mobile-menu-wrapper" class="flex-column">
    <div>Header text</div>
    <div>
        <ul id="mobile-menu" class="menu">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>Footer text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I only remove flex-column from the #mobile-menu-wrapper i seem to lose the   justify-content: space-between vertically (as its supposed to do on an horizontal flex). And with your second solution the background is weird, because its lacking the minus padding of the row element I guess.